# How to make SSH port fowarding for HTTPS?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, https

I've created the following port forwarding:

```
ssh -vL localhost:4433:example.com:443 remote-linux-host
```

<sup>Note: I'm using `4433` on my local instead of `443` to avoid running with `sudo`.</sup>

however when I go to `https://localhost:4433/`, after ignoring the certificate check, there is the following error (on both Chrome and Firefox):

> 404 - Not Found

Same when using `curl`:

```
$ curl -s https://localhost:4433/ | html2text
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
****** 404 - Not Found ******
```

How do I make the port forwarding for HTTPS?

My aim is to open `https://example.com/` (which works fine over HTTPS) on my local (port 4433) via remote server.

Comment: "404" means the server is working fine, it just can't resolve the URL into anything sensible.

Comment: The `https://example.com/` URL when going directly works fine.

Comment: Yes, and it also sends a completely different `Host` header.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let´s suppose that example.com is 93.184.216.34.

One of the methods could be as follows.

Do:

```
ssh -L 4433:93.184.216.34:443 remote-linux-host
```

Define in your local `/etc/hosts` in the machine using the browser:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

And then open in the browser: https://example.com:4433/

In this way, it will send the correct `Host` header.

Beware of browser/resolver DNS caches after creating the hosts entry.

Comment: I suppose I could use 127.0.0.2 also, so as not to break any other loopback functions.

Answer (score 4):

To keep hostnames, SSL certs, etc. all happy, you could use the `-D` option to create a dynamic SOCKS4/5 proxy.

```
ssh -D 4444 username@ssh-hostname
```

Then on local machine set firefox/chrome to use said proxy.